# problem in Stream.read() method in c#.net

Tags: c#, stream

```
public static void ReadWholeArray (Stream stream, byte[] data)
{
    int offset=0;
    int remaining = data.Length;
    while (remaining > 0)
    {
        int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);
        if (read <= 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException(String.Format("End of stream reached with {0} bytes left to read", remaining));
        remaining -= read;
        offset += read;
     }
}
```

size of byte array data is 2682
on the first iteration of while loop 
the value of read is 1658
on the next iteration
after executing the line

```
int read = stream.Read(data, offset, remaining);
```

the program is not responding

what is the problem?

Comment: Knowing the kind of stream is kind of important to be able to answer you correctly

Comment: why do you have to read data from stream manually?

Comment: Grzenio !  What is the other way to read data from stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is providing your stream is blocking until data is available.  From MSDN's docs on [Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx):

> The implementation will block until at
>   least one byte of data can be read, in
>   the event that no data is available.
>   Read returns 0 only when there is no
>   more data in the stream and no more is
>   expected (such as a closed socket or
>   end of file)

You can set a read timeout on the stream to prevent blocking forever.

As an aside, note that reading from the stream will move the current position, so with your offset logic you may be skipping large chunks of the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set a ReadTimeout at the stream and there is no data so the call blocks until data is available.

Check the properties of the Stream .ReadTimeout and .WriteTimeout.

Also, have in mind that you know the data you need but not how much data will come (fails, bugs, etc) so you should check that too.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. This code will read bytes from stream to the byte[]:

```
    public static byte[] GetBytesFromStream()
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:/pic.jpg", FileMode.Create);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        fs.Close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

Comment: This still has the issue of FileStream.Read not returing all the data, so you would need a loop to make sure all the data is read.